# Should I change my Keras code to run it on GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, cpu

Let's say I wrote my keras model, training and testing, on a CPU based tensorflow, and now I decide to use GPU, besides the 4 points mentioned above, should I change something in the way my code is written ? To be able to be compiled on GPU ??? Or my keras code could remain the same and still work on GPU. Thank

Comment: Everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

It should just work on the GPU, there is generally only environment requirements for it to run on the GPU, like having a gpu-enabled backend (tensorflow-gpu), CUDA/CuDNN installed, etc.

This assumes of course that your code does not force the model to a CPU, for example, using the `with tf.device("cpu")`, or using layers that do not have a GPU implementation.